# using numberWithFloat, but I want to trim the float to 1 decimal place first

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I can add a float to my dictionary and that works well:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.longitude floatValue]]
```

But is there a trick to set the decimal place to 1 digit also?

There are currently sometimes 6 digits after the decimal place and I do not need this accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", self.longitude] floatValue]];
```

Comment: This will not always lead to just on digit, as still rounding errors can occur.

Comment: When will this not give 1 decimal?

Comment: @Darren - Take an example: If I have the number 123456789.012346789 and I convert it to a string with %.1f, I would then get 123456789.0 as you would expect. If I then convert it back to a float using floatValue, I would get a floating point number that is as close as possible to 123456789.0, but it may actually be something like 123456789.001 internally. I don't recall the specific mathematics involved, but if you run through some example code it is very possible to see this happen. Using double instead of float makes it less likely, but it is still possible.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's best to just let the computer store what it will for a floating point value, but if you're only interested in displaying one decimal place for the user, you can just format it as such when outputting the number, such as to a UILabel or UITextField. However, there is no real benefit in time or space to be gained by truncating to a single decimal place before storing the data -- it will take the same amount of space and time either way.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers don't actually work that way. Each floating point number describes a value that is as close to the number you are trying to represent, given the resolution possible with the data type you are using (i.e. a double can describe your value more precisely than a float).

As @psoft suggests, your best bet is to let the computer take care of those details and only worry about this when you need to display the value.

If you really don't want to represent a number that is floating point, then you can consider using NSDecimal or its object wrapper NSDecimalNumber. These allow you to more generally represent specific values without resorting to the details of how floating point numbers are represented. My guess, however, is that you don't need to do this. Just using a float (or double) and don't worry about precision it uses internally.